# couldn't style react components with external css

Tags: css, reactjs

My react file isn't picking up my external styles.css

index.js :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./css/styles.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h1 className="upper-deck"> Hello world </h1>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

styles.css:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.upper-deck {
  font-size: "90px";
}
```

Project folder format :

[image: folder format]

Comment: Use react css module based styling  reference https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp

Comment: try removing quotes `"` around value of `font-size`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use quotes for scaler values in CSS. Remove the quotes around the pixel value for the font size.

```
.upper-deck {
  font-size: 90px;
}
```